# logstash filters: Using message timestamp in @timestamp field

Tags: logstash

currently, my doc looks like this (rubydebug output):

```
{
       "Timestamp" => 2016-06-20 12:51:14 UTC,
       "EventDate" => 2016-06-20 12:51:10 UTC,
         "Message" => "Failed to create the specified culture en-AF.",
       "ProcessId" => 660,
      "ProviderId" => "92bd94ca-02d2-5632-8907-3c6321d43fca",
    "ProviderName" => "epicuro",
            "Task" => 63133,
        "ThreadId" => 5100,
         "Version" => 0,
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2016-06-20T12:51:57.706Z",
            "type" => "epicuroLogs",
             "@id" => "epicuro.Api_2519358737299533641_FFFFFFFB"
}
```

I want to use the data from the "Timestamp" field as data for the "@timestamp", but I cannot figure out how to do it. It looks like @timestamp requires a string, but Timestamp is some kind of object? (notice the missing quotes). The date filter expects a string as input from what I can tell.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this. Hope it's what you want.

```
date {
     match => [ "Timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
     timezone => "UTC"
}
```